# Using Meld as external diff tool with Tortoise SVN

Tags: tortoisesvn, diff, meld

I have Tortoise SVN but I don't like the diff tool. Is there a way to use Meld with tortoise SVN? I know tortoise has an option to set external diff tools, but I am not sure how to use that with meld.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Download meld from http://sourceforge.net/projects/meld-installer/
2. Unpack the downloaded zip archive into "Program Files" or wherever you want it to be installed. This will create two folders, named "meld" and "python".
3. Start "meld.exe" from the "meld" folder. If you get a Meld window opened, then you have installed Meld successfully.
4. In TortoiseSVN, select `Settings`, then go to `External Programs -> Diff Viewer` on the left panel. In `Configure the program used for comparing different revisions of files`, browse to the Meld executable, "meld.exe", in your "meld" folder. Click on Apply.

That's it!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Worked fine for me. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it does not seem to work because by default tortoise seems to send " %merged %mine %base %theirs" which meld cant stomach on windows. If you set up custom rule in "advanced " only passing 3 instead of 4 files, meld opens OK

Answer (score 13):

With Meld 3.12 on windows this didn't work for me when merging.

My 'Merge Tool' command is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\meld\meld.exe --auto-merge --output %merged %mine %base %theirs`

Comment: Almost there ; according to Meld settings page (version 3.16.2), the order is "Remote, Merge, Local" ; so the correct parameters are `--output %merged %theirs %base %mine`. The only difference is that you get the remote file at the left, instead of right, so it works in both ways, but seems more logical to follow Meld convention (which can be reversed in Meld settings as well). You can add `--auto-merge` if you want Meld to attemp automatic merging where possible. Would be great if it could mark the file as resolved for git when saving the merged file.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me (Meld 1.8.6):

```
meld %mine %merged %theirs --output %merged --auto-merge
```

Super fancy: three-way merge with extra tabs for [mine vs base] and [theirs vs base].

```
meld %mine %base %theirs -o %merged --diff %base %mine --diff %base %theirs --auto-merge
```

https://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2012/09/three-way-git-merging-with-meld.html

Answer (score 0):

Especialy for merging 3-ways conflicts, under Windows, with Meld 1.8.6, this helps me :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\meld\meld.exe %mine %base %theirs --output %merged --auto-merge
```

But I do like the extra tabs of ryascl also.