# Using meld together with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, meld

I use VS 2017 and I want to view a file changes in meld from visual studio, or call meld for file from Visual Studio comfortably. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

While I can't say if VS 2017 behaves the same as VS 2019 in that regard, VS 2019 seems to respect the Git settings.

Meld can be configured as the default diff and merge tool for Git, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119866/setting-up-and-using-meld-as-your-git-difftool-and-mergetool).

It is also possible to configure it for Tortoise set of tools, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804444/using-meld-as-external-diff-tool-with-tortoise-svn), should you wish to use that as an alternative for managing Git repositories.

If you are using a different source control provider, hopefully the above examples with syntax will help you figure out the correct configuration in Visual Studio.

Effectively, the variables needed are: `%base %mine %theirs %merged`
along with options `--auto-merge --output --diff`.

Answer (score 1):

[Meld Diff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielroedl.meld-diff) lets you use `meld` to compare files or folders from `visual studio code` directly. This extension open two files (or folders) in the external tool `meld`.

To install, launch `VS Code Quick Open` using *(Ctrl+P)*, paste `ext install danielroedl.meld-diff`, and press *enter*.

Checkout the documentation [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielroedl.meld-diff).

Comment: Didn't he write "Visual Studio 2017", not "Visual Studio Code"?

Comment: @AlenSiljak You are right. The question is about Visual Studio 2017. My bad. I have not tested `Meld Diff` in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is Visual Studio support for meld, but you have some alternatives.

You can use the integrated tools to view file changes.
You can use it like this in cmd:

```
devenv /Diff SourceFile, TargetFile, [SourceDisplayName],[TargetDisplayName]
```

Next to that there are also some addons such as [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikkoHalttunen.VisualStudioComparisonTools) which offer some comparison functionality

Comment: Installer says, that VS17 may be not stabil after apply this plugin.